# Is there a way to create one switch statement for alike variables?

Tags: c, switch-statement

If I have a set of states like the ones below, is there a way to have the appropriate `file_state.testing#.foo` in the switch statement?

This is merely informational, as I've been trying to wrap my brain around if it's possible or not.

Underneath there is a section called `IDEAL SCENARIO`, and it is basically what I'm proposing if it's possible. The state table I'm getting these variables from is non-editable and each `file_state.tesing#.foo` has a case 1 and 2(the same case 1 and 2).

So without having to list them all, I wanted to see if there was a way that I could know the number and only write the switch case once instead of the amount of testing version there are. I'm not sure how to better explain, but I hope someone has some insight or if there is a better approach I can take.

```
file_state.testing1.foo
file_state.testing2.foo
file_state.testing3.foo
file_state.testing4.foo
```

Ideal scenario:

```
switch("file_state.testing%d.foo", testing_num_var)
{
  case 1:
     //do something
     break;
  case 2:
     //do something
     break;
  defualt:
     ;
}
```

Right now, I would have to write it as

```
switch(file_state.testing1.foo)
{
  case 1:
     //do something
     break;
  case 2:
     //do something
     break;
  default:
     ;
}

switch(file_state.testing2.foo)
{
  case 1:
     //do something
     break;
  case 2:
     //do something
     break;
  default:
     ;
}

switch(file_state.testing3.foo)
{
  case 1:
     //do something
     break;
  case 2:
     //do something
     break;
  default:
     ;
}

switch(file_state.testing4.foo)
{
  case 1:
     //do something
     break;
  case 2:
     //do something
     break;
  default:
     ;
}
```

Comment: Is there a factor that prevents you from putting the switch statement into a function and calling it with the relevant parameter each time? Or conditionally load the correct selector into the variable you use in the switch?

Comment: Create an array. `int array[] = {file_state.testing1.foo, file_state.testing2.foo, ...};` Loop through the array. `for (int i=0; i<4; i++) switch(array[i]) { ... }`

Comment: What you really want is to loop over `file_state.testing*.foo`, but you can't because variable names exist at compile time, and loops exist at runtime.  You could cut down the typing with an X macro and call it as `X(1); X(2); X(3); ... X(50);`  Or, if you have to do this a lot, you could create an array of pointers to the `file_state.testing*` objects (perhaps with a similar X-macro), and then do `for (i = 0; i < N; i++) switch(my_array[i]->foo) { case 1: ... }`

Comment: @nanofarad Good point, I don't think there is a factor preventing that. I didn't think of that before. In this case that variable in the switch statement could come from any one of the 1-4 variables. Is there a way that I would know which one to use if I was to use a function? I think that may be what I pursue

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you! I am processing what you wrote at the moment and wow great idea as well!

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you for the input! Currently investigating this as well!